# xcode for mac os 10.7.3

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, rvm

I recently got a mac and have very little experience with macos. 
**The OS is 10.7.3**a

I installed RVM , and noticed that while installing ruby it complained that gcc is not avail. [I dont have clang as well on the machine]

On the web, I found people asking to dnload xcode which has necessary lib bundled.

However I wasnt able to find a link to a compatible version of xcode for my OS.

Seems like I have managed to install xcode [an app comes up, which has archives, documentation, projects etc tab ..which are all empty].

Do I need to install 'xcode tools' instead ? is there a direct link avail somewhere , apples website is confusing and the one on app store cannot be installed on my OS.

This is probably a newbie question but I have seen many users trying to get a detailed procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Xcode should mean that gcc is now available, though you may need to install the "Command Line Tools". All Apple Developer downloads can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) including "Command Line Tools" for 10.7.

Comment: thanx !! ..I dont see gcc in /usr/bin . I dont think so its installed yet. Will install command line tools and check ..

Answer (score 0):

installing [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads) is enough to compile rubies in RVM

make sure that you read `rvm requirements` as it provides important information for installing rubies.